# How to disable Wordpress to reformat html tag in a post

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to make Wordpress do not reformat my html tag which I insert in a post?

For example, actually I want to insert a post like below.

```
 <aside class="col-md-4">
  <address class="lead">
    <strong>First row</strong><br>
    Second row<br>
    Third row<br>
 </address>
</aside>
```

Unfortunately when I bring the editor to the visual mode, my post reformat by Wordpress. It is then looks like this.

```
<aside class="col-md-4"><address class="lead"><strong>First row</strong>

Second row

Third row

</address></aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress editor has this issue and it is done for the people using the visual editor. To avoid wordpress reformat your html, you have to remove the filter that automatically adds paragraph tags

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

As a rule of thumb when you create your html, dont switch between visual and html tab. It causes to remove some parts of the html. A better way would be to use this plugin, "[PS Disable Auto Formatting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ps-disable-auto-formatting/)"

And if its still frustrating use a different editor for wordpress, there are plugins that override the default editor.